# Unemployed; applying for a tourist visa sponsored by my British friend from Scotland

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-ties

Is it possible for me to get a standard  tourist visa as an unemployed person? I live in the Philippines and my friend of almost 4 years wants to sponsor me for a visa. What documents do I need to present?

Comment: It is possible but highly unlikely. Do you have any ties to the Philippines such as dependent family, property? Any previous travel history to equivalent jurisdictions eg Schengen, Australia, USA? Does your long term friend support you in the Philippines and if so do you have evidence eg bank statements to prove that?

Comment: sponsor bank statement?we travel in asia before in hongkong,macau china,,but this is my first time to apply a standard tourist visa,,yes i have a ties to the philippines family,,.yes he supported me previously,,,

Comment: Related: [Unemployed person applying for UK visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/108439/3221). See this question as most of the advice there also applies to your situation.

Comment: Also you should be careful if your friend in the UK is actually a romantic interest. The UK dislikes when people try to conceal romantic relationships; you should disclose the fact if it is romantic. The UK will not disclose the relationship to your government, so you need not be overly concerned if your government would not like the relationship. If it is not a romantic relationship, then the UK will wonder why your friend wishes to sponsor you, and you should have a strong explanation for this.

Comment: its not a romantic relationship,his only a longterm friend and his married,,

Comment: @Ryan Patrick Sotelo There’s a guide to the documents needed to apply here https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk If reading that and the question linked to by Michael Hampton in his comment doesn’t tell you what you want to know, please edit your question to explain your circumstances more fully and to clarify what you need help with.